# C# Add if check to code block (i have no experience, need help)

Tags: c#

So I have absolutely no experience with C# but I really need to make this change in the plugin that I am currently using for my Rust Game Server.
I want it to check whether the player belongs to a group or not before "skinning" items. From what I understand there is a built-in class that you can use to make this check. I just need help to make sure that the syntax looks good, that the logic seems to be right and so on.

So this is the function that is being executed everytime a player equips a skin.

```
public void SetSkin(string shortName, ulong skin)
{
    Skins[shortName] = skin;

    foreach (var player in Players)
    foreach (var item in player.inventory.AllItems())
    if (item.info.shortname == shortName)
        ApplySkinToItem(item, skin);
}
```

Somewhere around here I want to make a check whether the player belongs to a group.
Something similar to this...

```
if(player.IPlayer.BelongsToGroup("VERIFIED")) {
  // execute the skin function
} else {
  Reply(player, "You need to verify on Discord before you can use this feature.";
  return;
}
```

I am not sure if I am close to the solution or if I am tripping. But I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: You are looping all players but you want to return from this method if only one is not verified? I'm missing the parameter for the current player, because you want to tell him that he needs to verify on discord.

Answer (score 0):

You're along the right lines but you need to remove the return statement from the else statement otherwise you will exit the SetSkin method.

This is how you would structure your if statement but without knowing more about the other classes it's not possible to say exactly what you need to do

```
public void SetSkin(string shortName, ulong skin)
{
  Skins[shortName] = skin;

  foreach (var player in Players) {

    if(player.IPlayer.BelongsToGroup("VERIFIED")) {

      foreach (var item in player.inventory.AllItems()) {

        if (item.info.shortname == shortName) {
          ApplySkinToItem(item, skin);
        }
      }
    }else{
      Reply(player, "You need to verify on Discord before you can use this feature.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While you are technically correct I think the SetSkin-Method is not the correct method to implement this check. If I understand it correctly it will change the skin of all verified players as soon as one Player trys to equip a skin, and message all unverified players about a feature they can't use without them trying to actually use it. Deploying this function might make some players really angry :>

My best guess would be instead of getting all players in a foreach-loop trying if `this.BelongsToGroup` is an existing function, as the `SetSkin`-method might be part of the Player-class.

Comment: I agree with what @Compufreak says there, setting the skin in this place is likely not the best place to do it, I was just answering your question about where to place the if statement in the SetSkin method.